# Why does object state not change when calling methods with a pointer receiver from within a map?

Tags: go, function-pointers

Consider the following code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Person struct {
    Age int
    M   map[string]func()
}

func New() Person {
    p := Person{1, make(map[string]func())}
    p.M["1"] = p.Add
    return p
}

func (p *Person) Add() {
    fmt.Println("Age before mutating in Add", p.Age)
    p.Age += 1 // here age should become 3
    fmt.Println("Age after mutating in Add", p.Age)
}

func (p *Person) Run() {
    fmt.Println("Age before mutating in Run", p.Age)
    p.Age += 1 // here age should be 2
    p.M["1"]()
    fmt.Println("Age after mutating in Run", p.Age)
}

func main() {
    p := New()
    fmt.Println("age before", p.Age)
    p.Run()
    fmt.Println("age after", p.Age)
}
```

This produces output

```
age before 1
Age before mutating in Run 1
Age before mutating in Add 1
Age after mutating in Add 2
Age after mutating in Run 2
age after 2
```

Here `M` is a map member of a struct, it stores methods of the same struct against strings.

In main we instantiate a non pointer struct value.

Then we call a method `Run` on that struct which is defined to have a pointer receiver. This *should* share a pointer to the struct with the method, which should allow the method to mutate the original struct.

Within `Run` we call the function `Add` stored within the map, via the map. But this does not mutate the struct, in fact it seems to operate on the state of the object as it was when newly created.

Any changes within `Add` are lost by the time `Run` ends, although `Add` is also declared with a pointer receiver.

I suspect this is because the original object was copied into the map somehow when calling `p.M["1"] = p.Add`?

Why does calling the method with pointer receiver not mutate the object?

Playground link https://play.golang.org/p/CRer_rT8_sj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`New` returns a `Person` and not a `*Person`.

When you write

```
p := New()
```

it starts with `New` constructing a Person `pnew` and adding its Add method to `pnew.M`. Then it returns `pnew`.

Then this `pnew` is assigned to `p` which is a *different* variable. So `p.M` contains now `pnew`'s Add method. When you execute `p.M["1"]()` in Run `pnew`'s Age is incremented (which is unrelated to `p`'s age.